# Fetching web page, but need javascript to view page content

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, mechanize

Fetching data/form from a website, I tried **mechanize and selenium**, all failed.

## mechanize

the script looks like the below,

```
import sys
import mechanize
url ='xxx'
response2=br.open(url)
request = br.request
print (response2.info())
print (response2.read())
```

**output:**

```
Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
CacheControl: no-cache
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

... more content ...

<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the page content.</noscript>
</head><body>
</body></html>
```

## selenium

so I think maybe I can selenium to run js, like

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url= 'xxx'
driver.get(url)

print driver.context
print driver.title

print driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

but I failed again, the **result** is almost the same:

```
...
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the page content.</noscript>
...
```

I just want to fetch the right content/form from the site, and `submit` or `post` the data/form to server to simulate a web browser visiting action.

I have no ideas now, I do not know very much how selenium work, and waiting for your help, thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry, forgot the url, url is `https://onlineservices.immigration.govt.nz/?WHS`

Comment: can you try adding this..profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()..profile.set_preference("javascript.enabled", True..broswer = webdriver.Firefox(profile)

Comment: When I visit the page, they show me an image code to prevent non-human visitors. Clearly, they don't want you to fetch that data.

Comment: @codeiscool Someone found the image code too, but I did not see it. I do not know why. Maybe they have a IP filter for image code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Enable flash using the below profile.

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile

firefoxProfile = FirefoxProfile()

## Enable Flash

firefoxProfile.set_preference('dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so',
                          'true')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefoxProfile)
```

If, it still doesn't work use chromedriver instead of firefox, it seems to work in chromedriver by default.

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.30/